# mosquitto TLS what certificate to use for remote mosquitto_pub

Tags: tls1.2, mosquitto

I am trying to setup mosquitto MQTT server using TLS1.2 using lets encrypt certificates.

I have installed mosquitto and setup lets encrpypt.  My /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf is

```
listener 1883 localhost

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.atom.net/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.atom.net/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.atom.net/privkey.pem
```

On the server run mosquitto I can successfully publish and subscribe to messages

```
Sub 
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t test
hello

Pub
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.atom.net -t test -m "hello" -p 8883 --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

From another system on the Internet (or ESP32) - I get error when trying to establish TLS connection

```
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.atom.net -t test -m "hello again" -p 8883
Error: The connection was lost.
```

What cafile / certs do I need to pass to the mosquitto_pub?

Answer (score 5):

To enable TLS in `mosquitto_pub` you need to pass either `--capath` or `--cafile` on the command line.

On a linux system you should be able to just pass the same `--capath /etc/ssl/certs/` (assuming the distro you are on is using keeps their CA certs in the same place).

Or you can copy the chain.pem file from your broker to the other machine and use `--cafile chain.pem`

For something like a ESP32 you will need to work out how to include the chain.pem in the build you push to the device.

Comment: Yes on a 2nd Linux system - I got it to work using --capath /etc/ssl/certs/.  I assume this confirms that my mosquitto server is correctly built.

However on the 2nd Linux system, if I copy the chain.pem and use --cafile chain.pem.  I get Error: A TLS error occurred.

In wireshark I see that the mosquitto_pub client sends a TLS1.2 Alert message - Level Fatal, Description: Unknown CA.

The chain.pem file copied is valid as I can dump it contents using openssl x509 -in chain.pem -noout -text.

Comment: Got the same issue with `--cafile chain.pem`. If you know the root cause of this please share it.

Comment: You probably want the path to the `fullchain.pem` file assuming you are using letsencrypt certificates